# Is this a typo in the proof of separation theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, inner-products

I'm reading this theorem in my lecture notes

> [image]

**My questions:**

1. If $x^\star = 0$ then $f(x^\star) = \langle x^\star, x^\star \rangle = \langle 0, 0\rangle = 0$. How can I infer that $x^\star$, the projection of the origin $0$ on $A$, is not $0$?
2. Since $f(x) := \langle x^\star, x \rangle$. Should it be $f(c) := \langle x^\star, c \rangle$ rather than $f(c) := \langle c, x^\star \rangle$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not beautiful as  it should be :)) @CameronWilliams Maybe it save some time in typing LaTex :)))

Comment: If this is your professor's notes, suggest kindly that they switch inner products to \langle and \rangle. Using < and > is very non ideal because LaTeX doesn't do the spacing right and honestly it's really tacky and seems lazy.

Comment: I will suggest it to him in this afternoon @CameronWilliams :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $C$ and $D$ are disjoint so $0$ does not belong to $A$. Hence the projection on $A$ cannot be $0$.

2) There is no difference between $\langle a, b \rangle$ and $\langle b, a \rangle$.

Comment: Thank you so much :))